# Query slow in neo4j comparing relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a small changetracking application I am building. I wanted to learn graph databases in the process. I have made a model where I have a changetracker with multiple runs checking items. In run A I found 1,2,3,4,5 and in the next run I might find 1,2,4,5,6.

So I made a simple model

```
(:ChangeTracker)-[:Has_Run]->(:Run)
(:Run)-[:NEXT]->(:Run)
(:Run)-[:HAS_Found]->(:Item)
```

the following query end up being quite slow when benchmarking (50.000 Items results in query times of > 10 seconds)

```
    PROFILE
MATCH
    (t:WebsiteTracker {Id : 'fde6fd1f-a899-5295-b73b-63fa75d131f4'})-[:HAS_SiteMapRun]->(lastRun)<-[:NEXT*0..2]-(run)
WHERE NOT (lastRun)-[:NEXT]->()
with t,run

MATCH
  (run)-[:NEXT]->(runNext),
  (runNext)-[:HAS_Found]->(itm)
WHERE
  NOT(run)-[:HAS_Found]->(itm)
RETURN
  t.Id, t.Name, run, itm
ORDER BY
  runNext.Start
```

I guess the part `NOT(runPrev)-[:HAS_Found]->(itm)` is the culprit, but how could I make my query better?

As expected the part `NOT(runPrev)-[:HAS_Found]->(itm)` is hitting every item node, the results look ok though.

[image: expanded plan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions), you can use apoc.coll.pairsMin() to get the adjacent pairs of each run, and use apoc.coll.subtract() on the collections of items to find the new elements that weren't present in the previous run.

This requires Neo4j 3.1, as we're using pattern comprehension to obtain the list of items for each run.

Something like this:

```
MATCH
  (t:ChangeTracker)-[:HAS_Run]->(run)
WHERE
  t.Id = 'fde6fd1f-a899-5295-b73b-63fa75d131f4'
  AND NOT (run)-[:NEXT]->()
MATCH 
  (runPrev)-[:NEXT*0..7]->(run)
WITH t, runPrev
ORDER BY runPrev.Start
WITH t, COLLECT({run:runPrev, 
  items:[(runPrev)-[:HAS_FOUND]->(itm) | itm]}) as runs
WITH t, apoc.coll.pairsMin(runs) as runPairs
UNWIND runPairs as runPair
WITH HEAD(runPair) as runPrev, LAST(runPair) as runNext
WITH t, runPrev, runNext, 
  apoc.coll.subtract(runNext.items, runPrev.items) as newItems
RETURN t.Id, t.Name, runNext.run as run, newItems
ORDER BY
  run.Start
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this later today

Comment: No luck.... Collecting the found items is slower than querying using the first query. I guess the information doesn't change a lot, so I will add extra properties to the HAS_Found relation. And use a cron job to regularly do the checking for none checked HAS_Found relations. checking every single HAS_Found, and add property if it is a new find, or an old find, or a temporary last find.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate, I wasn't sure if doing a collection subtraction would beat out your pattern matching, looks like that approach is out. Could you add the expanded PROFILE of your query to your description? Sometimes that holds a clue on some place to optimize.

Comment: I have dropped neo4j in favour of dgraph.io. Speed for my dense graph is quite a lot faster. And I never figured out how to improve the performance. At some point I couldn't even get transactions committed anymore. Still this was the only pointer in some direction, so I am accepting this answer as the answer.